# is it possible to change https page to http without full page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

Our site we have some pages like accountsetting which are loading in HTTPS, when we navigating to HTTP page we are changing the url in javascript and the entire page is reloading.. 
Our website is a single page application created in Backbone.js is there any better way to handle this?

This is what we are doing..

```
    ACCELERATOR.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

            routes :{
                'categoryHome(/:Type)(/:catId)' : 'homeAction',
                'account_settings(/:nickname)': 'accountSettingsAction',
                'trolley': 'trolleyAction',
                '*actions': 'defaultAction'
            },
            homeAction : function(){
                //some action
            },
            accountSettingsAction : function(){ 
                    if (location.protocol=='http:') { // cheking for https page 
                        var domain = document.domain;
                        var accountPage = "https://"+domain+ "/account.shtml#/account_settings";
                        window.location.assign(accountPage);
                    }elase{

                    }
            },
            trolleyAction : function(){

                    if (location.protocol=='https:') { // cheking for https page 
                        var domain = document.domain;
                        var trolleyPage = "http://"+domain+"//home.shtml#/trolley";
                        window.location.assign(trolleyPage);
                    }elase{

                    }
            }

    });
```

is there any better way to handle this?.

Comment: Use https in everything, or http in everything and problem solved.

Comment: If your site is a single-page app, why are you changing URLs? You should be using AJAX. If necessary, enable CORS to access HTTP from an HTTPS page or vice versa.

Comment: No, you should just load everything with https. If you want to override, you can always shoot of a http ajax request through backbone

Answer (score 0):

IF you have sensitive information, don't mix, just stick to *HTTPS* or go from single page to another page to handle the sensitive transaction.

It all depends on your workflow in the application and what makes sense.